# Best library for xyz

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, not-constructive

Already a few times I have seen questions being closed because people were asking "What's the best Ruby library for doing XYZ?".  I see the point that such a question, in general, may lead to endless discussions.  However there are many cases where this is not the case.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345683/best-ruby-library-for-excel-files

Having dealt with such libraries big time, I know that the spreadsheet gem is with no doubt the best cross-platform gem when you need many features.  win32ole is certainly the best choice if you want to integrate with MS Office on the Windows platform.

After all it can be a big time saver knowing which library to choose for what.

BTW, here is a counter example, asked by myself, that has not been closed:

[SOAP and Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702513/soap-and-sinatra)

So maybe instead of closing questions like this, one might suggest: hey, can you rephrase your question to point out what kind of use case your interested in.

Comment: Questions can be re-opened. I rather close the question, then *if* the question has been rephrased to be constructive, you can always nominate it for reopening.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I see... I wasn't aware of the fact that questions are reopened

Comment: BTW, why is this question downvoted so much? ;)

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: it was downvoted because people disagree with you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So maybe instead of closing questions like this, one might suggest: hey, can you rephrase your question to point out what kind of use case your interested in.

These two options are not mutually exclusive.  Questions that are asking "what's the best library for X?" should be closed as not constructive.  If they're improved with specifics, they can be reopened later.

**Note:** They really should be completely rephrased to ask "How do I do X?" and if the answer includes an example for using a library, great.